# How to call python file in repo in databricks from data factory outside DBFS?

Tags: azure, python, azure-data-factory, databricks

In Azure Databricks I have I have a repo cloned which contains python files, not notebooks.

In Azure Data Factory I want to configure a step to run a Databricks Python file. However when I enter the /Repos/..../myfile.py   (which works for Databricks Notebooks) it gives me the error "
DBFS URI must starts with 'dbfs:'"

How can I reference a python file from a report which is not in dbfs?

[image]

NOTE I see a duplicate question here but the answer was just to wrap it in a Databricks Notebook - OK workaround but when I do it I get "No module named 'my_python_file'"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096408/how-to-create-a-databricks-job-using-a-python-file-outside-of-dbfs

Comment: what databricks runtime is used?

Comment: 8.x but could also setup 9.1

Comment: Files in repos are supported only since 8.4, but better to take 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference

After all the mucking around, we decided to build a Python package (wheel) which can be imported to Databricks as a library. This can then be installed with %pip install /dbfs/..../*.whl and the package is then accessible to notebooks.